# bootstrap reordering columns to minimize the size of a given row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently working on a dashboard for a web app (based on bootstrap).

I have a row with a couple of widgets in one row. The user can activate the widgets of their choice.

The app is structured like this:

the dashed div is the row. the columns are within it.

The columns have different heights depending on their content. I'd like to reorder them so the row itself doesn't take up too much space. is there a way with bootstrap to move the (in this example) green div directly below the blue one?

thank you very much in advance.

html:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6 h-1 blue">
    col6
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 h-2 red">
    col6
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 h-3 green">
    col6
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.row{ width: 800px; margin: auto; margin-top: 10px; border: 1px dashed fuchsia; padding: 10px}

.blue{ background-color: #0000ff22; border: 1px solid blue }
.red{ background-color: #ff000022; border: 1px solid red }
.green{ background-color: #00ff0022; border: 1px solid green }

.h-1{ height: 100px;}
.h-2{ height: 300px;}
.h-3{ height: 50px;}
```

[image]

Comment: You may search a tools like IsotopeJS https://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes/masonry.html

Comment: thank you Bazaim, I'll check it out

Comment: If you do not require all the magic in isotope then you can take a look at CSS columns for a more basic solution. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

**.html**

```
<div class="row dFlex">
  <div class="col-6 width50">
    <div class="col-12 h-1 blue">
        col6
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 h-3 green">
      col6
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 width50">
    <div class="col-12 h-2 red">
      col6
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

**.css**

```
// your css

.dFlex{
  display: flex;
}

.width50 {
  width: 50%;
}
```